# Problem when booting, like old TV but when log in back to normal

Tags: boot, drivers, display

I have Axioo laptop using SIS Mirage 3 (SIS M672+SIS968 Chipset)
When I turn on my laptop, BIOS no problem, when booting ubuntu, problem with display like old TV (broken) but when log in back to normal .... and my next problem my resolution can't 1280x800
Any solution for my problem ?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)

Answer (score 2):

Just install startupmanager from the software centre or synaptic. Select the right resolution for your Boot screen and plymouth ( one that your monitor will support ). Next time when you log in the display will not be broken.

Comment: does startupmanager supports GRUB2 already ?

Comment: yes it does. Works perfectly on my maverick box.